# Multiple relationships between same entities (Sender & Recipient)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've got 2 entities. User and Message. A Message has a Sender and a Recipient. Both of which are users.
I want to expose navigation properties on User for "SentMessages" and "ReceivedMessages". What Fluent configuration is required to define this? I've tried a number of combinations and keep running into an exception:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Message_dbo.User_Recipient_Id' on table 'Message' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

My Entities look like:

```
public class User{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public virtual IEnumerable<Message> SentMessages {get;set;}
 public virtual IEnumerable<Message> ReceivedMessages {get;set;}
}

public class Message{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Content {get;set;}
 public virtual User Sender{get;set;}
 public virtual User Recipient{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable cascade deleting through Fluent API.
You cand do this in you context class:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
                        .HasRequired(a => a.Sender)
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey(u => u.Sender).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Recipient)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.Recipient).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
```